# Why does the media query which works in devtools "toggle device toolbar" mode doesn't work in Chrome browser?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

There is no problem when examining the part of my code related to media query in devtools "`toggle device toolbar`" mode. But after closing the preview, I found that the code didn't work  in browser. Why is this happening? I think it's related to Chrome browser. Because my code is working properly in Firefox.

```
// Main CSS

div#top-header {
    grid-area: theader;
    background-color: #FA6938;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 5px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

// This is still working

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) { div#top-header { padding: 0 15px; } }

// This code is running in "toggle device toolbar" mode but not running when I close the preview

@media screen and (min-width: 1120px) { div#top-header { padding: 0 14%; } }
```

Comment: Maybe devtools change your "width" of window and it seems like media query doesnt run

Comment: No, it opens at a width above 1120 px. Thanks.

Comment: If first statment is 600px and second is 1120px then it should ovverride rule. Try to add flag '!important' to second media.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you figure out what was the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

In the 'head' of your html ?